# express-session session tbl is not created

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, session, express-session

Good day
I have a problem with express session.

On my laptop the code works as is, but as soon as I try to save the session to a different database on a different system, the sessiontbl is not automatically created.

here is my app.js:

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const session = require('express-session');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const MySqlStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);

const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const loginRouter = require('./routes/login');
const panelRouter = require('./routes/panel');
const logoutRouter = require('./routes/logout');

const app = express();

//Session Setup
const options = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  user: 'dbuser',
  password: 'dbpassword',
  database: 'db'
};
const sessionConnection = mysql.createConnection(options);
const sessionStore = new MySqlStore({
  expiration: 108000000,
  createDatabaseTable: true,
  schema: {
    tableName: 'sessiontbl',
    columnNames: {
      session_id: 'session_id',
      expires: 'expires',
      data: 'data',
    } 
  }
}, sessionConnection);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// Use middleware
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'mysecretnotonlaptop',
  store: sessionStore,
  resave: false, 
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
  }
}));

app.use(fileUpload({
  limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 },
}));

// Routes Setup
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/login', loginRouter);
app.use('/panel', panelRouter);
app.use('/logout', logoutRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

and this is how my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "aktiv-radio-control-panel",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "devstart": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.4.0",
    "express-mysql-session": "^2.1.8",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.1",
    "formidable": "^2.0.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "qrcode": "^1.5.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.1",
    "socketio": "^1.0.0",
    "speakeasy": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Session store will automatically create "sessions" table. You need to create custom table & columns in MySQL  Workbench first. Then set createDatabaseTable: true, to createDatabaseTable: false. You can read the documentation to understand more.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mysql-session